# Looking for a solution to a tkinter error and efficiency/design problems

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

The code below represents my first steps into making a calculator on python using tkinter. The idea is to put the numbers on a grid accordingly, and then make the all of the necessary adjustments. The problem here is that I get the following error:
`_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack`
I'm aware that this is because of the `canvas.pack()`, but isn't it necessary for the background? How can I separate them in the most efficient way possible? On that note, is there a way to put all of the buttons/grids together using fewer lines of code? Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *

#Creating the window function (?)
window = Tk()

#Creating a frame and a background for the calculator
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, height=700, width=700, bg="#83CFF1")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(window, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.7, relx=0.15, rely=0.15)

#Creating the buttons for the calculator
button1 = Label(window, text="1")
button2 = Label(window, text="2")
button3 = Label(window, text="3")
button4 = Label(window, text="4")
button5 = Label(window, text="5")
button6 = Label(window, text="6")
button7 = Label(window, text="7")
button8 = Label(window, text="8")
button9 = Label(window, text="9")
button0 = Label(window, text="0")

#Adding it to the screen
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button3.grid(row=0, column=2)
button4.grid(row=1, column=0)
button5.grid(row=1, column=1)
button6.grid(row=1, column=2)
button7.grid(row=2, column=0)
button8.grid(row=2, column=1)
button9.grid(row=2, column=2)
button0.grid(row=3, column=1)

#Ending the loop (?)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should the buttons be children of `frame` instead of `window`?

Comment: Why do you need the `Canvas` for? A `Canvas` is mostly used to draw shapes on. If you just want some background color, you can directly change `window`'s background: `window.configure(bg=...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create `buttons` using Python list `comprehension`.
- For the grid placment use `i // 3` (floor division) and `i % 3` (modulo) inside a for loop.
- Then just simply add the last button manually.

This code below will do the trick:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(window, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.7, relx=0.15, rely=0.15)

#Creating the buttons for the calculator
buttons = [tk.Button(frame, text = i) for i in range(1, 10)]


for i, button in enumerate(buttons):
    button.grid(row =  i // 3, column = i % 3)

#Add last button 0
buttons.append(tk.Button(frame, text = 0))
buttons[-1].grid(row=3, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```